# Point Set Similarity Metrics

Tags: computational-geometry

I am looking for some quick metrics to take to measure the similarity between two sets of points, such as distance between centroids, amount of overlap etc

I would ideally like to take a few more metrics to improve the accuracy of the basic similarity measurements, but the key feature is that they ideally need to be fast and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the application, *similarity* could mean *anything*.

- The number of points.
- The dimension of the points.
- The average, variances, and covariances of the coordinates.
- The position, volume, or orientation of a bounding box of type ...
- The radius and position of a smallest enclosing ball.
- The volume and ... of the convex hull.
- The ... of clusters of kind ...
- The density of points in ...
- The ... of ...
- ...

There is probably a real-world reason *R* why a set of points *P* are distributed in a certain way. So try to deduce *R*, and compare the *R*'s for similarity instead.